# Fail with error 'UniswapV2Router: EXPIRED'

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, uniswap, project-fork

I forked UniswapV2's [factory](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x9446DaC273DA4c86b1e6f944b0398765471B9496) and [router](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x458290cb6948061d1e639cc884a97cd80b2ee981) and deployed them in Kovan using remix

[image: addLiquidityETH]

I also made sure that I am sending an ETH
[image]

I also made sure that I approved the tokens
[image]

But I am getting this error when trying to send the transaction
[image]

When I proceed, the transaction always fail, here is one of them, it's returning a `Fail with error 'UniswapV2Router: EXPIRED'`, this is the same error I am getting when doing the test in my local in truffle

https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x59624fb39db924eff817f872001718cfaa95c825c052f21f4fd3cb033250d23b

Please take note that transactions are successful when using UniswapV2 Router's contract address in remix

Comment: Have you tried increase gas?

Comment: did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a problem with the `deadline`, maybe the timestamp you are running the function on your computer is higher than the time you are setting as deadline.

Print the `block.timestamp` to know its value and get an idea of the possible error.